# How to call a function from checkbox onclick or onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclick

I have a form in which i want to disable or hide two input fields by selecting a checkbox. I can easily do it when on document.ready, but since i am appending those fields the function does not take effect. How do i call the function with onClick?

**Here's my working code**

```js
$(function() {
  $(checkbox).click(function() {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
      $('#appTimes').find('input').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#appTimes').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="appTimes" id="appTimes">
  <input name="stopTime1" type="text" id="stopTime1" />
  <input name="stopTime12" type="text" id="stopTime12" />
</div>
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

**And this is what i am trying to do:**

```js
function boxDisable(e) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(e).find('input').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $(e).find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="appTimes" id="appTimes">
  <input name="stopTime1" type="text" id="stopTime1" />
  <input name="stopTime12" type="text" id="stopTime12" />
</div>
<input name="checkbox" onclick="boxdisable(appTimes);" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

**---EDIT---------------**
Let me redefine: My code is using .**append** to create **multiple** instances of the above code. Since the amount of append is unlimited i am unable to define the checkbox with `$('#id')`, because there might be hundreds of them like `$('#id1')`, `$('#id2')`.. etc. I need a function that avoids mentioning the exact element id's, is called **onClick** by the **checkbox** and affecting beforehead div, which is **also** appended.

Comment: I'm quite confused on what you're trying to do here,  the var `appTimes` is not defined...  Perhaps you mean `onclick="boxdisable('.appTimes');"`?

Comment: no need for if/else, you use prop to set and unset disabled, not attr/removeAttr, which takes a boolean `$(e).find('input').prop('disabled', $something.is(':checked')); `

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works :)

```js
function boxDisable(e, t) {
    if (t.is(':checked')) {
      $(e).find('input').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $(e).find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="appTimes" id="appTimes">
  <input name="stopTime1" type="text" id="stopTime1" />
  <input name="stopTime12" type="text" id="stopTime12" />
</div>
<input name="checkbox" onclick="boxDisable(appTimes, $(this));" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Yes, but i  am **appending** which means can not use $('input#chekcbox') and i need to use $(this)

Comment: This works! I didn't know i can put `$(this)`  with the onclick call. Thank you

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works on this snippet, but not on JSFiddle?

Comment: @RaTre when script is executing, jQuery is still not loaded. It is one of solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/6ynu4mtc/

Comment: You shouldn't use `attr` and `removeAttr` for this, you should use `prop`. `$(e).find('input').prop('disabled', t.is(':checked'));`

Comment: @Popnoodles thank you. Maxim it's still not working on my code. Do you think it might have something to do with .append()? I copy and paste the code 1:1 and it's doesn't seem to take any effect

Comment: @RaTre well, show me your jsfiddle. Do you use `append('$code')` or `append("$code")`

Comment: Nice! How does the t.is() method work? can you tell us more?

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy it checks if element matches selector passed as a parameter to is() function, or not. So, if you select div element and run $(elem).is('div') it will return true.

Answer (score 6):

If the elements do not exist at the time of doc ready, use `.on`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
        //do your stuff here
    });

});
```

[jQuery .on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: How would you define the checkbox since i'm appending and i have the possibility to append more than one and all of them will have the same functionality. I need a function to do the job and use $(this) to define the checkbox

Comment: $(e.target) should get you the checkbox that has changed and fired the event. This code puts the listener on the document, so any checkboxes added to the document after doc ready will still have the event bubble up and fire your code.

Comment: You do understand, that .append() takes place **after** doc ready, right?

Comment: Yes, the use of .on, bound to the document, allows you to, in effect, bind events to things that do not yet exist.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the `onclick` attribute.  What your code is doing is attaching a new onclick handler after the user clicks.  That's probably not what you want.

You should also use `prop` instead of `attr` for changing `disabled`.

Since the element you want to attach your event to may not exist on document ready, attach it to the nearest ancestor that you're sure will be there.

```
$( function() { // wait for document ready
  $( '#parent-div' ).on( 'click', ':checkbox', function( e ) { // attach click event
      $( '#appTimes' ).find(':text').prop( 'disabled', $(e.currentTarget).is(':checked') ); // set disabled prop equal to checked property of checkbox
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Really good points. But this doesn't fix his logical problem.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown What is the "logical problem"?

Comment: Fair enough, I added an additional paragraph for that.

Comment: I'm trying to **avoid** waiting for document ready and element id's. I want to use $(this) for the checkbox and a variable for the div with, containing the inputs

Comment: You can attach the event to something higher in the DOM if the element doesn't exist at ready time.

Comment: @Vohuman hes saying that those inputs are appended in the code. So, when appended, if the checkbox is unchecked, those inputs stay enabled. He wants them to get disabled at this time. `but since i am appending those fields the function does not take effect` -> That is because the checkbox click event isn't called on the append.

Comment: This is a far better answer than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $(checkbox).click(function() {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
      $('#appTimes').find('input').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#appTimes').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="appTimes" id="appTimes">
  <input name="stopTime1" type="text" id="stopTime1" />
  <input name="stopTime12" type="text" id="stopTime12" />
</div>
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```