# Jquery execute function after programmatically checking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i execute a function after programmatically setting a checkbox to checked?
After this completes, I would like to call a function:

```
$(event.target).parents(".row").first().find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true)
```

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
$((event.target).parents(".row").first().find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true), function () {
        Edit();
    });
```

Thank you for all of your responses. My issue was that the checkbox was being unchecked in the Edit function

Comment: You're overcomplicating this - just call `Edit()` on the following line of code after setting `prop()`. JS is not multithreaded, so operations are executed in sequence (unless they are explicitly async, which this is absolutely not)

Comment: ^ Right. In case you still want a callback -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28372632/7867822

Comment: Hey, JavaScript checkboxes have a `change` event (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438068/perform-an-action-on-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked-event-on-html-form ) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event - does that address your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) isn't [async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean), so you can guarantee the next line will be executed after the first one.

Consider this small example:

```js
// Ensure checkbox isn't checked on load
console.log($('#check1').prop("checked"));  // FALSE

// Call .prop
$('#check1').prop("checked", true);

// Call function
edit();

function edit() {

  // Show function result
  $('#edit').text('Call inside edit();');
  
  // Ensure prop has been executed
  console.log($('#check1').prop("checked"));  // TRUE
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="check1" type="checkbox">
<div id='edit'></div>
```